# Induced homomorphism from homology group of circle to homology group of $\mathbb{R^2-}0$ is trivial

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $C_r$ be a circle of radius $r$ in complex plane, and let $f:C_r\to\mathbb{R^2}-0$ defined by $f(z)=z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_0$ and suppose that it has no zero on and inside the circle $C_r$.

How to show that

$$f_*:H_n(C_r)\to H_n(\mathbb{R^2}-0)$$

is trivial?

I know that both $C_r$ and $\mathbb{R^2}-0$ are homotopic to 1-sphere $S^1$. Hence the homology groups are isomoprhic. Then why do not we have that $f_*$ is just identity?

Comment: Oh sorry, $f$ is not an inclusion, $f(z)=z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_0$ and suppose that it has no zero in the circle $C_r$.

Comment: @Watson I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a homotopy $H_t: C_r \to \Bbb R^2 - 0$ given by $H_t(z) = f(tz)$. At time $1$ this is just $f(z)$ and at time $0$ it is the constant map $f(0)$. Note that $f(tz) \neq 0$ by our assumption on $f(z)$. Therefore $f$ induces the same homomorphism on homology as the constant map does, and the latter clearly induces the zero homomorphism.

Edit: When I say that the constant map induces the zero homomorphism, I am assming that $n \geq 1$. For $n=0$, $f_*$ will be an isomorphism.

Comment: totally equivalent but maybe a little bit easier to visualise, the map $f$ factors through a disk by assumption.

Comment: Do you mean that "induces the same homomorphism on homology as the constant map does" is that it is null-homotopic? And why is "the latter clearly induces the zero homomorphism"? I cannot grab what you mean. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Riccardo what do you mean by $f$ factors through a disk?

Comment: @ChenMLing Yes, my homotopy demonstrates that $f$ is null-homotopic. Let $g(z) = f(0)$ be the constant map that $f$ is homotopic to. Then $g$ is equal to the composition $C_r \to \{f(0)\} \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^2 - 0$, and $H_n(\{f(0)\}) = 0$ for $n \geq 1$. Thus $g_* = 0$ for $n \geq 1$.

Comment: Oh I see. OK thank you :)